# Getting memcheck error while running non blocking TCP code

Tags: c, tcp

I am trying to implement non blocking calls using select() in my server code. I have 5 clients and one server.
   When I run it with valgrind, I'm getting the following errors. Could anyone help me where I'm going wrong and how to fix them?

```
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001B32E6: strnlen (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F7F10: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F8C72: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001FAFF5: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0AC7: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0C98: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0B9F: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000B19C: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Generic (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0BB6: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000B1B5: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Generic (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0BB6: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0BF8: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0C28: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BC15: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BD17: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BD42: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BD5B: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0C67: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB005: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F6D6D: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0BEC: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001F0BF8: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BC1E: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BC23: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BC31: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x10000BC3D: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5311==    at 0x10000BD63: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Ivybridge (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C37: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001EE4B7: __sflush (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C70: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Syscall param write(count) contains uninitialised byte(s)
==5311==    at 0x1002FB976: write$NOCANCEL (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001EE4C6: __sflush (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F0C70: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001FB08C: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1002209CE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100220CA0: __xvprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F6B91: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x1001F49F7: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000ED1: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
Message Data: 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x1001BADA1: isspace (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000844: getmsg (in ./server-tcp)
==5311==    by 0x100000EEF: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5311==    at 0x1001BADAD: isspace (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000844: getmsg (in ./server-tcp)
==5311==    by 0x100000EEF: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5311==    at 0x100000870: getmsg (in ./server-tcp)
==5311==    by 0x100000EEF: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311== 
==5311== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==5311==    at 0x1002FCC1E: write (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x10015D5C8: start (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==5311==  Address 0x104802eee is on thread 1's stack
==5311==  in frame #0, created by write (???:)
==5311== 

 RECEIVING ON PORT NUMBER 5919....
Socket 0 have data to read
Readline Error
Message Data: 
==5311== Invalid read of size 1
==5311==    at 0x100216879: strtol_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==5311==    by 0x100000F13: main (in ./server-tcp)
==5311==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for a SO question. Have you tried compiling with -g? Valgrind will give you more useful information if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

You read upto 1023 bytes from the socket with `if((n = read(sockfd, buffer, 1023)) <=0)`  and fail to set `buffer[n]` to`'\0'` before passing `buffer` to `getmsg`.  `getmsg` may parse beyond the end of the buffer and cause a buffer overflow.

More importantly, you assume `num_wrds` is at least `7` and invoke `atoi` and `strcpy` with potentially uninitialized pointers `w[0]` through `w[6]`. If the data read from the socket is only a fragment, this will cause undefined behaviour, very much what you are experiencing.

You should bufferize the data read from the socket to parse complete words or lines at a time and check for errors systematically.

You should also use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to avoid potential buffer overflows.

There are probably many more problems in your code, but try and fix these first.

Comment: The count variable `n` should be passed to `getmsg()`. It isn't appropriate to assume that the data read is null-terminated. It might be binary. Adding and assuming a trailing null byte also makes it impossible to deal with buffers that are full.

Comment: @EJP: Given how it is parsed and handled, the data is not binary.  Passing `n` to `getmsg()` is an alternative to null terminating the buffer, but it does not solve the more major problem: the OP reads a chunk of data from the socket and assumes it is a single and complete set of words.  Unless he uses UDP, the transmission may be split and repacked along the way.  The only guarantee is the byte sequence order, not the packet sizes.  Bufferization is needed to make this client/server dialog reliable.

Comment: You can't append a null to a full buffer. Passing the count around with the data is the only correct solution.

Comment: @EJP: I beg to differ: the code is no longer there, but `buffer` is defined as an array of` `1024` bytes.  The OP reads upto  `1023` bytes into it, so you most certainly **can** append `'\0'` to a full buffer.  The problem is you should not rely on the buffer contents to be a consistent set of values because transmission over the socket can break down packets into smaller ones or concatenate them into larger ones.  Neither appending a `NUL` byte nor passing `count` accounts for this major problem. Don't you agree on this?